# Do not download file with curl if file already exists locally

Tags: curl

I am currently doing with curl:

```
curl https://example.com/file -o file
```

If I already have a file called `file` in my directory, it will be overwritten by this command. Instead, I would like to return an error message telling that the file already exists.

Is it possible to do so only using curl? I have not seen a flag to do it and I am not running the command in a bash script thus I cannot use a comparison operator before running the command.

Comment: what about: `[[ -e file ]] || curl https://example.com/file -o file`?

Comment: `curl https://example.com/file -C - -o file` might be what you need. It tries to resume from where any missing parts are, and exiting if the file is already complete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Testing for the existence of a name in a directory may be done with the `-e` test:

```
if [ -e "filename" ]; then
    echo 'File already exists' >&2
    exit 1
fi

curl -o "filename" "URL"
```

If you don't want to terminate the script at that point:

```
if [ -e "filename" ]; then
    echo 'File already exists' >&2
else
    curl -o "filename" "URL"
fi
```

The test will be true if the name exists, regardless of whether the name is that of a regular file, directory, named pipe or other type of filesystem object.

See `man test` on your system.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47226987/983169) regarding the `-C -` curl option. Essentially, resume the download. If the file is already complete, then there's nothing to do. This will call the server for resume checking.

Comment: If it is an unrelated file, it will also possibly end up corrupting it.

Comment: You are correct. It’s not part of an idempotent process and can help provide acceleration and recovery options if implemented well. I use this in combination with a file name check, and in other places with redirect support for various intents.